# How to get client machine username to authenticate the user with ldap

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap, client

I have an application build in `angular 7` and to authenticate a user I am using `LDAP`. To authenticate the user I need to send the username `(i:e client machine name)` in the API.

Previously I was using `jsp` for the same and it gives me client machine name. I have an API on which I request with key `username` & `password`.  Now I am migrating the application to angular.

> Please let me know how can I get the client machine name in angular
>   application or an alternative solution.

I tried the `os` module & also tried with some node packages but unable to get the client machine name as it is server-side.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible in browser JS.

Comment: Google is your friend too.. I did a simple search.. and [Authenticate Angular with LDAP using Auth0](https://auth0.com/authenticate/angular2/ldap/) seems to be popping up frequently..

Comment: @rmjoia The above url is to authenticate with ldap server but **I am looking for auto-login feature, for that i required the client machines `user Name`**, so i can send the username to authenticate the user by getting the system `user Name`. 

>My major concern is to retrieve the username of client machine from which they >are requesting.